# Problem updating or adding web reference in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wsdl

I have an application that has been working with for a very long time, in Visual Studio 2015. Today, I added a line to the Salesforce.wsdl.xml file, and then right-clicked on the web reference in my project, and clicked on the menu item to update the web reference. This failed with the error below. So, I removed the reference, regenerated the Enterprise WSDL file, and attempted to add a web reference to the newly generated file. I get the same error with that one. I don't understand what has changed that is causing this problem. I did this a month ago without any problems.

I have included a screenshot showing the problem as well.

Any help/insights would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
---   ERROR message BEGINS  ---

> The document at the url file:///C:/DEV/XYZ/XYZ Application/Web >References/Salesforce.wsdl.xml was not recognized as a known 
>   document type.
>   The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML

---   ERROR message ENDS  ---

Comment: Suggest you Google to find an online WSDL validator and run the same file through that. If the validator is unhappy then it is a problem with your manual edit and you should go back to an earlier version of the file.

Comment: I will look into that. I have tried going back to two of the previous versions of the file that were working, with the same result, though.

Comment: I went to https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com and uploaded the file to analyze it...came back with no errors.

Comment: This is just so bizarre, because I have done this for years, with the involved application, and have never had this problem. I just created a new project, and tried to add a Web reference, and had the same result, so it's not something about the project/solution. I also tried doing it in Visual Studio 2012, with no success.

Comment: Yep weird unless some setting or the underlying libraries that somehow both 2012 and 2015 run on have changed. Can you get a more complete version of the error message? (When manual steps are involved the odds are still in favour of some slight difference in the manual steps causing the problem though.)

Comment: I am certain that the issue is not one of manual changes as I have tried the previous version and an unaltered newly generated version. Any ideas as to how I could get a more complete version of the error message. I don't see any way to view more of the error message, and I tried selecting displayed text, to select text I can't see, but can't select any more than I can see?

Comment: Visual Studio might have a log somewhere that includes more information but I don't know anything about it. A quick Google found this that might or might not be relevant https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4626b79-b5ed-4a7c-88df-04aa7fbacc17/where-can-i-find-visual-studio-2010-error-logs,

Comment: I can't find a file that contains the error.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot below shows that there were three lines in the WSDL that needed to be deleted. I found the issue by comparing the current WSDL contents to the contents of a WSDL file that was generated like five months ago, the last one that I found I could successfully add a Web Reference to. There were tons of differences, but this was the difference that mattered, for some reason. Anyway, once I deleted the three lines, highlighted in green, I was able to add a Web Reference!

[image]

Comment: The `<b>` element doesn't look like a valid [XML Schema XSD element](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_elements_ref.asp). Is it possibly an artifact from how the WSDL was exported from Salesforce?